# iTunes Photos sync tab eternally spinning wheel

Tags: itunes, photos, data-synchronization

iTunes 12.9.5.5 on Mac Pro Mojave 10.14.7

*There will be a 500 point bounty awarded for any useful answers on this question. I will award retrospectively, as otherwise it will timeout in a week.*

Note: This structure has been working perfectly for years/decades. Recently this symptom was displayed - after I got a new iPhone 13 Pro Max, which has subsequently been returned to Apple, replaced with an SE2. Since that first error, now all iPhones/Pads display the same symptom - yet an iPod Classic I've since dragged out of retirement does not. The Classic cannot 'see' Photos.app as a sync option, only my user's ~/Pictures folder. All the other devices have always been set to use the Photos.app Library.
This, I consider a vital clue.

I've so far tested three devices - an iPad & two iPhones, all show the same symptom. When a connected device is selected, to show the Summary & sync pages, all tabs work fine except for the Photos tab, which just shows the spinning wheel; no headers, no info at all - even the ability to switch off sync would let me try twice, un-sync, re-sync.

[image]
<sub>Intentionally small image</sub>

Sync works [except no photos are transferred] Music, documents & other data will sync & backup just fine. A full Restore also works, though I only tested that on one device, I think it's sufficient to show that generally the connectivity & iCloud sign-ins are working OK.
All devices are different generations running different iOS versions, 12.5.1, 14.8 & the newest an iPhone SE2 on 15.0.2 [now 15.1].

Photos.app itself appears to be behaving normally.
I use no iCloud sync at all for photos, all are stored locally in the Photos.app on a separate internal drive.

Fixes tried so far - first, everything from Linc Davis' answer on the Apple Forum - [itunes circle wont stop spinning when photos sync](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7406630)

Restart device
Connect to root USB
Delete iPod Photo Cache [backed up first]
Check Photos album names [no slideshows, no soundtracks]
Repair Photos Library

Then additionally,

Boot Mac in safe mode
Launch iTunes in safe mode
Check drives - boot APFS & storage HFS+ with Disk Utility and Disk Warrior - no issues.
Tested variations on permissions - default & ignore ownership.
Moved library to default location on boot volume & reassigned as System Library; repaired again.
Uninstalled [thoroughly] Dropbox & Google Backup & Sync - both of which may attempt to intercept images to save online.
Disabled Antivirus real-time protection.
Cloned boot volume to internal SSD [my fastest SSD is on a PCI riser which the machine thinks is 'external'.]
Tested with SIP on & off.
Tested an empty, brand new Photos Library file, in the default location [removing the other first].

To complete a full sweep of "things I don't know what they do but might help", in Onyx I cleaned all this lot..

[image]

Still no joy.

I did, rather surprisingly, persuade an ancient [2006?] iPod Photo to show me the Photos tab & successfully sync a few small selected photos. I thought that may have unclogged the same tab for the phones… alas not.
What is maddening is I can have both connected at once, & switch repeatedly from a perfectly cromulent iPod photos page, to a totally borked iPhone photos page.

Console shows these three messages over & over. I have no clue what they mean…

```
default 12:21:32.979042 +0000   deleted     com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension : 0
default 12:21:32.985231 +0000   deleted com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension : 0
default 12:21:32.988853 +0000   deleted removing filtered services: {("com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension")}    
default 12:22:33.038607 +0000   pkd plugin /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/PlugIns/iTunesCacheExtension.appex is still valid.
default 12:22:33.064951 +0000   deleted com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension : 0
default 12:22:33.081487 +0000   secinitd    iTunesCacheExtension[93640]: root path for bundle "<private>" of main executable "<private>"
default 12:22:33.101440 +0000   secinitd    iTunesCacheExtension[93640]: AppSandbox request successful
default 12:22:33.162911 +0000   iTunesCacheExtension    --> purgeable media items not enabled
default 12:22:33.162946 +0000   iTunesCacheExtension    returning 0 bytes for level 3
default 12:22:33.163021 +0000   iTunesCacheExtension    result: <private>
default 12:22:33.163162 +0000   iTunesCacheExtension    calling completeRequestReturningItems
default 12:22:33.163419 +0000   deleted com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension took 0.126815 seconds, returned: {
    "CACHE_DELETE_AMOUNT" = 0;
    "CACHE_DELETE_ID" = "com.apple.cache_delete";
    "CACHE_DELETE_URGENCY" = 3;
    "CACHE_DELETE_URGENCY_LIMIT" = 3;
    "CACHE_DELETE_VOLUME" = "/";
}
default 12:22:33.749416 +0000   iTunes  <ATHostMessageLink 0x600003740160> <-- Processing incoming message 'Ping':
{
    Command = Ping;
    Id = 214;
    Session = 0;
    Type = 0;
}
default 12:22:37.481806 +0000   deleted removing filtered services: {(
    "com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension"
)}
default 12:22:37.486918 +0000   deleted Purgeable op results: {
    "CACHE_DELETE_ELAPSED_TIME" = "0.002715253";
    "CACHE_DELETE_ID" = "com.apple.cache_delete";
    "CACHE_DELETE_NONPURGEABLE_AMOUNT" = 0;
    "CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_AVAILABLE" = 441937303;
    "CACHE_DELETE_URGENCY" = 3;
    "CACHE_DELETE_URGENCY_LIMIT" = 3;
    "CACHE_DELETE_VOLUME" = "/Volumes/OhDaSpace";
    "com.apple.AssetCache.builtin.CacheDelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.MailCacheDelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.ReportMemoryException.CacheDelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.Safari.CacheDeleteExtension" = 0;
    "com.apple.TMCacheDelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.activity_tracing.cache-delete" = 0;
    "com.apple.bird.cache-delete" = 0;
    "com.apple.cloudphotosd.cpl.cachedelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.cloudphotosd.ilmb.cachedelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.commerce.cachedelete" = 0;
    "com.apple.coresymbolicationd.cache-delete" = 0;
    "com.apple.desktoppicture.cache-delete" = 0;
    "com.apple.iTunesCacheExtension" = 0;
    "com.apple.ibooks.CacheDeleteExtension" = 0;
    "com.apple.imagent.cache-delete" = 441937303
```

Comment: Have you tried using Image Capture to transfer photos from iPhone/iPad to your Mac? I've found it a far more reliable method than iTunes/Finder.

Comment: I have no issues whatsoever getting photos *off* the devices, only back *on*.