# I am syncing my MacBook Pro OS 11.6 with my iPad 15.0.2. Music completes, but then it states "Reading Photos Library"

Tags: ipad, photos, data-synchronization

It has now been reading the photo library for 5 full days.  I have only just 7,000 photos on the Mac.  I have no photos on the iPad, because I deliberately cleaned up the iPad in the hope that after synchronising, my photos would all be on the iPad in the same arrangement as on the Mac.

I believe that when the Mac is reading the photo library, it may also be analysing each photo to see if it has dogs, birds, names, etc. (things you can search on).

I am reluctant to stop this process, in case I have to start over.
Can anyone give me some way of telling what progress it has so far made?

Or any advice at all?

Comment: What do you see if you flip to the Photos tab in the window? Maybe related to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/428872/85275

Comment: Tetsujin, thank you for trying to help.  What do you mean by "the photos tab in the window?"  In what window?  On the Mac or on the iPad?

Comment: On the Mac. Assuming a recent version of macOS, your iPad should show up as a connected device in the sidebar in Finder. Click on it to see sync details including the tab mentioned.

Comment: Thank you nohillside.  When I click on the iPad in the sidebar in Finder, I see revolving arrows alongside the highlighted iPad.  The screen shows details of the syncing process, and the status is showing as "Syncing (Step 4 of 5) - Reading Photos Library".   This has now been running 6.5 days.

Comment: I now see a small window called Activity, and the message in the window is "Updating "iPad Pro etc".