# Music app on MacBook is stuck loading iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music, music.app

I have my iPhone 7 which I've previously always synced with iTunes on my Windows laptop (there are 60 GB of MP3 files). I'm trying to replace the Windows laptop with my MacBook, which I've never connected to the iPhone. I've already transfered all the MP3s from the Windows laptop to the MacBook.

Now I'm trying to sync the iPhone to the MacBook, but when I connect the iPhone to MacBook via USB, the Music app is stuck on "Loading" (screenshot below). I understand 121 GB is a lot of space, but Music app should only be calculating the allocation summary. The iPhone's been connected to the MacBook for 6 hours, and nothing's changed. I'd appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: I have an SE 2020 that does that every time I try to access Photos. Never did figure it out. [sorry, that doesn't help you at all] ;\ https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/428872/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin I posted the fix for my issue, give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating to macOS 13.3.1